# csrf and cors errors in localhost development of webpacked vuejs/reactjs/angularjs website with django backend

Tags: django, reactjs, vue.js, webpack, django-rest-framework

How can I run my vuejs application on localhost and have it send its API calls to my deployed django rest framework backend without getting cors and csrf issues?

So far I have these issues:

- I can't read the cookie from browser because it's domain is not set to localhost. I need that to set the `X-CSRFTOKEN` header for django.
- I get CORS errors since localhost is not the same origin as my domain(example.com)
- I get error that referer does not match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I struggled with this for three days until I found this great solution.

I put the following in my `vue.config.js` and I initialized my http client with baseURL = '/api'

```
const fs = require('fs');
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '^/api': {
        target: 'https://example.com',
        ws: true,
        changeOrigin: true,
        bypass: (req, res) => {
          if (req.headers && req.headers.referer) {
            url = new URL(req.headers.referer);
            url.host = 'example.com';
            url.port = '';
            req.headers.referer = url.href;
          }
        },
        cookieDomainRewrite: '',
      },
    },
    http2: true,
    https: {
      key: fs.readFileSync('./cert/key.pem'),
      cert: fs.readFileSync('./cert/cert.pem'),
    },
  },
};
```

There is another option which is setting something like `local.example.com` in your hosts file and creating whitelists etc in your `settings.py` but this solution is way cleaner and better.

You can use the following command to generate your self signed certificates. For some reason I was getting authentication errors when not using https.

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365 -nodes -subj '/CN=localhost'
```